# Saving changes of only the nested transaction in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have code that builds data into object A. There is a transaction for doing that.
While collecting data, I need to insert object B into the database and use its ID for A. There are many levels of abstraction in saving A and B, so I cannot use the B's entity object as reference for A.

B is saved in it's own `BegingTransaction`, but while doing so, A is in the same Db Context and Change Tracker, and saving A with insufficient data produces errors causing a rollback. <-- undesired outcome.

Ideal solution for me would be that when saving B, only those objects that are created/modified within that, nested transaction, would be collected for saving and leave the ambient transactions objects alone. Is this possible? Any other work-arounds?

I tried creating more transactions, but I'm not fully aware of the effects of different Isolation Levels. Nevertheless, didn't work.

I tried creating another db context for saving B, but that resulted in deadlocks for an unknown reason. I guess it would also not play well when trying to rollback the ambient transaction.